# How to conditional select table rows using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I query this table if I wanna select rows with same CHANGE_KEY and SYSTEM_KEY = 1 and SERVER_KEY = 2, to clarify I'm not interesting in rows with only SYSTEM_KEY = 1 like the first row in the following table because SERVER_KEY = 2 is also needed, a correct result table will only contain the two last rows in the following table because the CHANGE_KEY 4 has both SYSTEM_KEY=1 and SERVER_KEY=2

```
   CHANGE_KEY  SYSTEM_KEY  SERVER_KEY  HARDWARE_KEY
    ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
    1           1           NULL        NULL
    1           NULL        1           NULL
    1           NULL        NULL        1
    2           NULL        1           NULL
    3           NULL        1           NULL
    4           NULL        1           NULL
    5           NULL        1           NULL
    5           NULL        1           NULL
    4           NULL        2           NULL
    4           1           NULL        NULL
```

Comment: I edited the question, sorry my english is bad.

Comment: Seems like you want CHANGE_KEY = 4 an a least one of following SYSTEM_KEY = 1 or SERVER_KEY = 2, I updated my answer

Comment: given your edit saying those last two rows should be the ones returned, I believe you want an `OR` clause and not an `AND`, so have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it's as easy as this.

```
Select * From MyTable Where Change_Key = 4 AND (System_Key = 1 OR System_Key = 2)
```

Comment: yeah I had to double check the question aswell just in case there was some caveat...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
table 
WHERE CHANGE_KEY = 4
AND 
    (
     SYSTEM_KEY = 1
     OR
     SERVER_KEY = 2
    )
```

EDIT: I made changes, following your edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CHANGE_KEY = 4
AND (SYSTEM_KEY = 1
OR SERVER_KEY = 2)
```

Edit: You've edited the question to say that the last two rows in the table should be in the result-set.  However, an `AND` will not achieve this, I believe you're looking for an OR so have modified my response.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE change_key = 4 AND system_key = 1 AND server_key = 2

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, i would write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CHANGE_KEY=4 AND SYSTEM_KEY=1 AND SERVER_KEY=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE change_key = 4 AND system_key = 1 AND system_key = 2
```